# PHP MySQL query returning NULL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that looks like this:

```
index  |  tag  |  posts
-------------------------
  1    | cats  |   9,10
  2    | a cat |   9,10
  3    | kitty |   9,10
  4    | meow  |   9,10
```

I am trying to just return the row that matches a search query.
I passed the search parameter using a simple `?search=cats`.
This is the PHP that I'm using:

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag = '$search'");
echo(mysql_num_rows($query));
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$print  = $result['posts'];
echo($print);
```

However the `mysql_num_rows($query)` prints 0 and the `$print` returns NULL. I can check it with `($print == "")`, it evaluates to TRUE and `mysql_num_rows($query)` returns 4.
I tried setting the search query to something that wasn't in the table and it retuned FALSE as expected. I also tried removing the `WHERE tag = '$search'` and it returns the table like it should.

Is there something I'm overlooking?

**Edit**

Took everyone's advice and the code I'm using now is:

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
var_dump($search); //prints   string(4) "cats"   just like it should
$queryText = "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag = '%".$search."%'";
echo($queryText); //SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag = '%cats%'
$query  = mysql_query($queryText) or die(mysql_error()); //no error
$rows   = mysql_num_rows($query); //this returns 0 and I know it should match 1 row
echo('rows: '.$rows);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$print  = $result['posts'];
echo($print); //empty
```

Still have the same problem. The `mysql_query` is retuning NULL instead of the row or FALSE if it doesn't match.

*(in the future I will use the `mysqli` API, but I would like to finnish this project in `mysql`. thanks for your suggestions and advice)*

Comment: 2 Things:
1. echo after $search = $_GET['search']; that indeed the search word was filled.
2. change the query to $query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag = '$search'") or die(mysql_error());
and tell us what is the output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Make sure you know EXACTLY what's being sent to the MySQL server.

`$queryText = "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag = '$search'"; print($queryText);` Also try putting `or die(mysql_error);` on the same line as the `mysql_query()`.

Comment: remember to use function `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: @OrelEraki I checked `$_GET['search']` and it indeed was what I wanted it to be. I also added `or die(mysql_error())`, but no errors were returned. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after referring to the above edit you made, here is the solution

Use "LIKE" instead of "=" when using wildcard "%"

So your query now should be

```
$queryText = "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
```

[I created the exact same db on my local system and ran the same code you gave, After making the above changes, It runs as expected]

Comment: According to the php manual ( [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) ) $_GET is already decoded and I shouldn't use the `urldecode()` function on it. Should I use it or not?

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then. I'm going to switch over to `mysqli`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code now.

**Remeber** when you want to debug something in PHP the faster way is **var_dump** not *echo*. Also you should avoid mysql_api because they are deprecated, use PDO instead [PDO on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

```
var_dump($_GET); // Just for debuggin if as something

$search = $_GET['search'];
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag = '".mysql_real_escape_string($search)."'");
// echo(mysql_num_rows($query));
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
var_dump($result);
//$print  = $result['posts'];
//echo($print);
```

Comment: I fail to see how that's going to solve the problem. It adds more security, but.. it's certainly not the answer.

Comment: He should know if $_GET has something first... That's the purpose.

Comment: It's not the answer, you should have added that as a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: Every others answer are equals.. just change some style and the code.

Comment: What an earth are you talking about?

Comment: I checked the `$_GET['search']` first and it did in fact contain what I wanted it to. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @thunder618 You're welcome, maybe EM-Creations will understand :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
echo $select_query="SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag = '".mysql_real_escape_string($search)."'";
$query  = mysql_query($select_query);
echo(mysql_num_rows($query));
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  print_r($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag = '$search'");
```

That is very dangerouse: It allow sql incersion code to your database. You must always escape all what you get from the client.

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']); //It require open database connection.
```

Note2:
mysql_query is obsolete, use mysqli instead ;-)

Answer:

If you have not answer, you probable has an error in an other part.
Try

```
//1) Look if your search has a correct value
var_dump($search);
//2) Replace the query with (just for debugging):
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag = 'cats';");
```

You may also use "tag like '%cats%'" if you want a more flexible search.

Comment: Thanks. I added the `'%cats%'` and `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the WHERE tage = '$search', it cannot return the table like it should because your mysql_fetch_array is not in a while loop... but that aside...

```
// make sure before you execute the code to check that $_GET['search'] is not empty

// start with escaping the search-value (for mysql-injection)
$search = msyql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);

// changed the query so it searches for tags containing the search value.
// if you would have records with tags "blue cat" and "red cat" it shows them both
// when searching for "cat"
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE '%".$search."%'");

// put the number of rows in a var
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);

// check this var if it's not 0
if ($num != '0'){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query){
        echo $row['posts'];
        // etc...
    }
} else {
    // 0 rows found
    echo "nothing found";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, when I removed the `WHERE tage = '$search'` I used `while($result[] = mysql_fetch_array($query))` to verify it. Thanks for the `'%".$var."%'` tip!